# Problem with partitions (deleted all of them)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

A few months ago, I had Windows 8 as the only operative system on my computer and I wanted to install Ubuntu, having both operative systems on my pc (dual boot). However, after supposedly installing Ubuntu, I wanted both Ubuntu and Windows 8 to appear on the screen when booting (so I could choose which one I wanted to work with), and that's when the problem appeared... in the terminal, I followed a tutorial that could make the dual boot work (I don't remember what I wrote) and, all of a sudden, all of my partitions were gone. I initiated the computer again and it would go straight to the BIOS. Then, after several tries, I somehow installed Ubuntu and have been working on it since. However, I know that all of my partitions are messed up and now that I need both Windows and Ubuntu on my pc, I want to delete the current Ubuntu that I have and start working on the computer like it didn't have any operative systems (install both Windows and Ubuntu from scratch). I really appreciate any help that you can give.

I attached a print screen of gparted (https://i.stack.imgur.com/50zte.png), which shows all of the partitions on the computer.

Comment: You should consider changing the title of the question to reflect the actual content. Since you are not trying to recover lost partitions, the title is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Then, after several tries, I somehow installed Ubuntu and have been working on it since.

That was a **terribly bad** idea. You should never, ever install a new OS on top of an old one you are trying to rescue.

Moreover... your screenshot shows that you managed to fill up ~600GB of stuff on the hard drive, which makes any recovery impossible.

> I want to delete the current Ubuntu that I have and start working on the computer like it didn't have any operative systems (install both Windows and Ubuntu from scratch).

Mmm ok, this is kind of the opposite of what the title would suggest. If you *don't* want to recover stuff, but instead you want to **completely erase** the data on the disk, it's quite easy. You have two ways.

## WARNING: Everything written in the following part of my answer will delete or at least seriously damage the contents of your hard drive. Don't use the following commands if you care about the data contained there. I am not kidding.

Having said that, let's start:

### The basic way

If you want your disk to "seem" empty, you can delete the partition table. For doing so, you can just blank some blocks at the beginning of your disk:

```
# DANGEROUS COMMAND, BE CAREFUL
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024 count=10
```

I've put up some numbers. Probably just one or two blocks could be ok, but just in case...

As said before, this will blank the partition table. This allows to see the disk as empty, however it doesn't give you a guarantee on security. What I mean is that people will still be able to recover most of your files by using specialized computer forensics software such as `testdisk`, `photorec`, `foremost` or the Autopsy Browser.

### The long, long way

Another option is to **completely wipe every single bit** on your hard disk. This can be done by not limiting `dd`. It's also useful to try a bigger block size to save a bit of time.

```
# EXTREMELY DANGEROUS COMMAND, BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8192
```

This could take up to some hour without giving you any feedback.

### Final remarks

It is your responsibility to make backups of data you need. You asked for ways to wipe your disk and I gave them, but keep in mind that taking care of your data is your duty.

Comment: And after doing that, what should I do to install Windows and Ubuntu? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Firstly install Windows. You can tell it to use the entire hard drive. Then install Ubuntu and the installer will ask you how to split the available space between the two.

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall Windows and Ubuntu after that, you need to create an NTFS partition for Windows and an ext4 partition for Ubuntu. You then need to install Windows first. If you install Windows last, you will be unable to reach GRUB2 on boot.

Comment: And how do I create those partitions? Thank you for the help.